# How to use Animated-Multi-level-jQuery-Dropdown-Plugin no errors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-plugins

I'm using Animated-Multi-level-jQuery-Dropdown-Plugin and i encountered the following errors:

> jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'length' of undefined
>       at Function.each (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
>       at Dropdown.addItem (jquery.dropdown.js:1274)
>       at Object. (jquery.dropdown.js:1185)
>       at Function.each (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
>       at Dropdown.addItems (jquery.dropdown.js:1183)
>       at Dropdown.addItem (jquery.dropdown.js:1269)
>       at Object. (jquery.dropdown.js:1185)
>       at Function.each (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
>       at Dropdown.addItems (jquery.dropdown.js:1183)
>       at Dropdown._populateList (jquery.dropdown.js:2380)

this is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">


    <link href="css/jquery.dropdown.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>

  <body role="document">

    <div class="container">

      <select>
        <option>Select Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
        <option>Option 3</option>
      </select>

      <!-- Html lists -->

      <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li data-dropdown-text="Item 2">
          <ul>
            <li data-dropdown-text="Item 2.1">
              <ul>
                <li>Item 2.1.1</li>
                <li>Item 2.1.2</li>
                <li>Item 2.1.3</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li data-dropdown-text="Item 2.2">
              <ul>
                <li>Item 2.2.1</li>
                <li>Item 2.2.2</li>
                <li>Item 2.2.3</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li data-dropdown-text="Item 2.3">
              <ul>
                <li>Item 2.3.1</li>
                <li>Item 2.3.2</li>
                <li>Item 2.3.3</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
        </div>



    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.dropdown.js"></script>
    <script>

            $('select, ul').dropdown();

    </script>
    <!--<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->

     </body>
    </html>
```

please help me I do not know where the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem, when I changed jQuery version to 1.12.4 problem disappeared.

Comment: Feel free to accept answer with a check button :) you are welcome